# How to configure remote submission to Apache Storm Topology with kerberos authentication

Tags: java, kerberos, apache-storm

I have an Apache Storm topology hosted on Linux servers with Kerberos security installed.

I wish to submit tests onto this storm topology from my remote windows machine.

I am having difficulty configuring my client to connect with Kerberos Authentication

I am stuck with this exception

```
SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

I have managed to submit remote MapReduce jobs using this client code

```
final UserGroupInformation userGroupInformation = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser(USER_NAME, UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser());
        final AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod = AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS;
        userGroupInformation.setAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod);

        userGroupInformation.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<UserGroupInformation>() {
```

What is the equivalent configuration for a Storm Topology?